# Перенос данных в форму input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Приветствую! Имею массив данного вида. Запускается код позволяющий сделать необходимое количество Div'ов, т.е клоны определенной формы. Они заполняются из массива, в данном случае выходит 3 формы с присвоенными данными из каждого массива. В каждой форме у меня вставлен Input позволяющий добавить элемент в коллекцию. Проблема в том, что я не могу отправить значения а1,а2,b1,b2 соответственно в data-name="" data-price="". Что приводит к тому что в коллекцию при нажатии кнопки приходит лишь 1 и тот же элемент из любой формы. ID Inпута меняется при копировании.

```js
var Toys = [a1, a2],[b1,b2];

<input id="Button" type="button" value="Add colection" onclick="href="#" class="cart" data-name="" data-price="">
```

Comment: Пробуйте подобным образом `$('#button').data('name', Toys[0]).data('price', Toys[1])`

Comment: Не верно. это многомерный массив, верно будет так - $('#button').data('name', Toys[0][0]).data('price', Toys[0][1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодарю, всех кто помог) 
Решил проблему немного иначе!
Все работает как и хотел!

```js
var Add = document.getElementById('Button');
Add.setAttribute('data-name', el[1]);
Add.setAttribute('data-price', el[5]);
```